# Spring Security LDAP authentication for production without LDIF

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I want to authenticate users against the Active Directory entries. I am trying to use Spring Security LDAP authentication for the purpose. All the references available online just talk about implementing the authentication mechanism with LDIF store. I couldn't come across any useful reference where it explains the real world usecase of LDAP authentication, one where we authenticate against an Active Directory setup of an organization. Even the [Spring doc says so](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/#:%7E:text=Using%20an%20LDIF%20file%20is%20not%20standard%20configuration%20for%20a%20production%20system.%20However,%20it%20is%20useful%20for%20testing%20purposes%20or%20guides.), but doesn't explain it,

> Using an LDIF file is not standard configuration for a production system. However, it is useful for testing purposes or guides.

I am just not able to get my head around this LDAP authentication. I somewhat understand a typical LDAP architecture and its entries' structure but am not able to understand how does one authenticate against his/her company's Active Directory when one is not aware of the values of `uid`, `ou`, `dc`.

One approach to know the entry path on Windows is to run `gpresult /r | find "OU"` as per [this SF post](https://serverfault.com/a/22873/479950), which prints out something like

`CN=Malick\, AsifKamran,OU=Users,OU=Home Users,OU=Office Areas,DC=regionname,DC=company,DC=net`

Do all users have the same entry path like above ? Is this information sufficient enough for me in order to authenticate via Spring LDAP?
I tried following the [Spring LDAP Authentication guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/), but to no avail. Each time I enter my system credentials(as my system is configured for AD), the login page complains of Bad Credentials.

Following along the above guide, below is my code :

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0}, ou=Users, ou=Home Users, ou=Office Areas")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=Users")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://regionname.company.net:3268/dc=regionname, dc=company, dc=net")
            .and()
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }
}
```

I am just not sure if at all my code is correct. I just tried to be as sensible as I could while populating the arguments of `userDnPatterns`,  `groupSearchBase`, `url`, `passwordAttribute`. Like I said, I'm just not sure if at all my approach is correct. All I have is login page that gives me `Bad Credentials` message.

I would also like to know how should a developer go about when he has the LDAP authentication task at hand; where to look up for entry path format and other things.

Comment: The general procedure is to get something unique from the user such as his email address, bind to the directory as an admin user, search the user space for that user by that unique attribute, which gives you the user's full DN, and then attempt to bind as that user using the password the user supplied. If that succeeded, the login is successful and you can then proceed to retrieve the user's attributes, roles, group memberships, whatever you need.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for the response. But I am not sure how to translate your advice to a runnable code, which is exactly the main point of my question. Is the admin binding still required if the user is already having a valid entry in the AD? How do I search the user, i.e. by setting which attribute (cn or uid). The user will be entering his employee-id in the username field and all the info that I have about the path is just the `cn`, `ou` and `dc` which `gpresult` returned. I am also not sure if any attribute such as `uid` exists in our AD record. How do I deal with this situation?